# Regex pattern to match nested contents of fixed depth

Tags: regex, nested

As far as this answer shows ([Can regular expressions be used to match nested patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns)) we cannot create a regex that can be used to match a infinitely nested pattern. But can we create a regex pattern that matches up to N nested occurences of that pattern?

For example how could we create a regex that matches comments like this up to 3 layers deep?

```
   <*
      Comment of depth 1 containing another comment
      <* 
         That is a comment of depth 2 containing another comment
         <*
            Nanananananana BATMAN!!!
         *>
      *> 
    *>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said in a comment that you will integrate the regex ain a BNF definition that will be fed up to the library "mpc".

Try to define the multiline comment like this:

```
mlcomment    : "<*" (<mlcomment> | /\*[^>]|[^*]/)* "*>" ;
```

I tried it with mpc and it works.

You can have comments not matter if they are nested. For example:

```
<* A multiline comment here
<* Another one here *> *>
```

The downside of this is that you cannot have multiple asterisks on the closing tag. This:

```
<* A multiline comment
second line **>
```

is not going to work. But I think it is as close as it gets with the limitations of mpc.

Answer (score 0):

```
<\*[\s\S]*?<\*[\s\S]*?<\*[\s\S]*?\*>[\s\S]*?\*>[\s\S]*?\*>
```

A simple way .See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/129

You can use `recursive regex` here.

```
<\*(?:(?R)|(?:(?!<\*|\*>)[\s\S])+)*\*>
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/131

Comment: Your comment works only with nested comments of fixed depth 3. Is it possible to make it to match UP to depth 3?

Comment: @TheArtist which language?

Comment: Just a personal project :)

Comment: @TheArtist yeah still i mean what would you be using ? php?java?

Comment: I am using C++, but the thing is that i will integrate the regex in a BNF definition that is fed up to an external library i am using. The library is this: https://github.com/orangeduck/mpc

Comment: @vks The library he is using does not support those regex features. Take a look at this issue: https://github.com/orangeduck/mpc/issues/28